# seeking work around for google maps geocode query for hyphenated addresses

Tags: google-geocoding-api

**I'm looking for a solution that works from a backend server**, rather that from a client; as the first answer points out, there exists a nice way to do that that I'm already aware of.

There is a known (though closed, and not yet re-acknowledged) bug with google maps API and it's handling of addresses that contain hyphens.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=481

my example address is: 45-56 42nd Street, Queens, NY, 11104

the exact particulars of the bug are unknown to me, but the basic result is that the '45-56' is not treated as a "street_number", and a query for a perfectly valid address in Queens yields many incorrect result; most importantly, without a single correct result.

```
curl 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&components=country%3AUS&address=45-56+42nd+Street,+Queens,+NY,+11104' | grep formatted
         "formatted_address" : "56 East 42nd Street, New York, NY 10017, USA",
         "formatted_address" : "95-56 42nd Avenue, Queens, NY 11368, USA",
         "formatted_address" : "94-56 42nd Avenue, Queens, NY 11373, USA",
         "formatted_address" : "45 West 42nd Street, New York, NY 10036, USA",
         "formatted_address" : "242-56 42nd Avenue, Queens, NY 11363, USA",
         "formatted_address" : "196-56 42nd Road, Queens, NY 11358, USA",
         "formatted_address" : "28-56 42nd Road, Queens, NY 11101, USA",
```

I'm looking for a workaround, as I prefer not to wait for this issue to be acknowledged/fixed.

I have not yet been able to get anything to work, and am hoping someone else has run into this issue; perhaps found a workable alternative formatting that results in correct address/geocode lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) works:

(although as I don't know the area, it could be wrong, but it does return a single result with the "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED"):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=45-56%2042nd%20Street,%20Queens,%20NY,%2011104&geocode=1

Comment: thanks for that, this can be done w/ js code explicitly as `var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( {'address': '45-56 42nd St, Queens, NY, 11104' }, function(data, status){console.log(data);});` which will work in a web-client, I have not been able to get it, or an alteration to work from a server, which is the situation I'm dealing with. I should have made that explicitly clear.